# how to test my website's look on phones, offline

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net-mvc, responsive-design, localhost

I know there are some great websites to help us test our websites on different resolutions, one of my favorite is [quirktools.com](https://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http://stackoverflow.com&w=640&h=360&a=38).

However, the problem is-the website I'm working on is not online yet. I'm working on localhost right now. However, I really need to check how it looks on different resolutions before it goes online.

So, is there any desktop application that works with localhost and help me to achieve this?

I tried google sever times, but can't find anything.

Please tell me if you know.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
PS: I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: If your smartphone is on your LAN, just surf to `http://ip-of-computer/`?

Comment: assuming you have a phone yourself and assuming that when you refer to localhost you mean you have a local server, then you could change your apache configuration to allow other local devices to access your site. From there just use your phone to access your local server using the local ip address.

Comment: is that possible if my iPhone is just connected with its phone cable? I just tried, and didn't open the page. I think i need some configurations, right?

Comment: @Happy ninja I'm working on ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: don't you have a local server?

Comment: @Niels, I just tried that and it works nicely.

Comment: the website is located in the URL like http://localhost:64922/.

Comment: i set up a wifi network from my laptop. connected to the network from my iPhone. typed my IP address. doesn't open. tried localhost:64922 instead, didn't worked either. i know i'm doing something wrong... but what?

Comment: If you have the Safari browser, you can try the UserAgent option which is under Develop menu.

Comment: After connecting to network, you have to open `http://<Your-Machine-Name>:64922` or `http://ip-of-computer/` not localhost, replace local host with machine name or ip of your computer...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it existed at time when the question was asked, but now Chrome supports Device mode. See more here:

- https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

To use it:

- Toggle Developer tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
- Toggle Device mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)

It looks something like this:

[image]

Check the above link which gives more information about how to use and what all the options mean. I find it superior to using physical devices for quick testing when doing development for two reasons:

- It is obviously faster to toggle between these then to reload on phone / tablet
- You can test multiple devices, even the ones you do not own

Obviously, it is not perfect and is only an emulator. Check the limitations section on the above link. It is worth doing a test on real hardware when you are nearing the going-live date.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you are using localhost, I am guessing you are using xampp, wamp, or the like. All you need to do is pull up a terminal(*nix)/command prompt(windows), ifconfig(*nix)/ipconfig(windows), get the ip address, and put that into your mobile browser while on wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Check your responsive website offline or localhost server http://helpersway.blogspot.com/2014/02/How-to-Check-Your-Responsive-Website-Offline-and-Localhost-Server.html

Comment: "link only" answers are not good because links get broken eventually. Add a complete answer and then add references or cited sources.